# Ubuntu 18.04LTS freeze when maximizing a Window

Tags: gnome-shell

I use ubuntu 18.04LTS launched from virtual Box on Windows 10
My version of gnome-shell is 3.28.3 No extension of gnome-shell are installed

When I maximize any window the system is freezing. If I look at the CPU History nearly 100% of the resources are used

The only solution I found is to kill gnome-shell with the command
killall -3 gnome-shell

Do you know if a patch exists to solve this issue ?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `sudo lshw -C video`. Thank you for helping us help you!