# Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS problems when maximizing a Window

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell

I have a problem similar to this one that was previously reported
([Ubuntu 18.04LTS freeze when maximizing a Window](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1094155/ubuntu-18-04lts-freeze-when-maximizing-a-window?rq=1)). In my case I've installed Ubuntu 18.04LTS with Linux as my OS.

When I maximize any folder the system is freezing. The files inside the maximized folder only appear as I move the cursor. I can see with top command that some times gnome-shell is consuming 100% of the resources. I have gnome-shell 3.28.3 version.

How can I fix these problem? I tried with killall -3 gnome-shell, and reinstalling gnome-shell. But the problem it's solved only temporarily.

Thanks in advance

I include the output of *sudo lshw -C video*

*-display

```
   descripción: VGA compatible controller 
   producto: GM107GL [Quadro K620]
   fabricante: NVIDIA Corporation
   id físico: 0
   información del bus: pci@0000:02:00.0
   versión: a2
   anchura: 64 bits
   reloj: 33MHz
   capacidades: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuración: driver=nouveau latency=0
   recursos: irq:37 memoria:de000000-deffffff memoria:c0000000-cfffffff memoria:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memoria:c0000-dffff
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to ask ubuntu. I made some edits to your post to make it more clear. in the future if you say "I have another question with the same problem" you should like to where the first question was.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! It's unclear (at least to me) what other question you are referring to. Please [edit] your post to include a link to the question you mention if you think it relevant to your question.

Comment: @ElderGeek I hope my question is clearer now, thanks for your comment.

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `sudo lshw -C video`. Thank you for helping us help you!